# Hyper-parameters of Gaussian Processes for Regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, hyperparameters

I know a Gaussian Process Regression model is mainly specified by its covariance matrix and the free hyper-parameters act as the 'weights'of the model. But could anyone explain what do the 2 hyper-parameters (length-scale & amplitude) in the covariance matrix represent (since they are not 'real' parameters)? I'm a little confused on the 'actual' meaning of these 2 parameters.

Thank you for your help in advance. :)

Comment: You might wish to look around on [stats.se] for information on this.

Comment: @Meadowlark Bradsher  thank you for your comment. Did you mean that the optimization is stuck on a local peak?  I'm not that familiar with hyper-parameters...Can I assume that: do cross validation over 2 hyper-parameters, compute the corresponding log-likelihood and then select a pair close to the peak value of log-likelihood as the initial hyper-parameters for optimization?

Answer (score 1):

First off I would like to point out that there are infinite number of kernels that could be used in a gaussian process. One of the most common however is the RBF (also referred to as squared exponential, the expodentiated quadratic, etc). This kernel is of the following form:

[image: foo+bar]

The above equation is of course for the simple 1D case. Here l is the length scale and sigma is the variance parameter (note they go under different names depending on the source). Effectively the length scale controls how two points appear to be similar as it simply magnifies the distance between x and x'. The variance parameter controls how smooth the function is. These are related but not the same.

[The Kernel Cookbook](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/duvenaud/cookbook/index.html) give a nice little description and compares RBF kernels to other commonly used kernels.

Comment: Ah yes he moved to Harvard after his PhD I believe and the site went too

Comment: Link updated again. http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/index.html